# charset="utf-8" вставлен, а проблема отображения русских надписей остается! Что делать?

Tags: javascript, кодировка, share, ya-share2

При такой проблеме дается совет:
Если кодировка страницы отличается от UTF-8, при подключении скрипта кодировку нужно указывать явно:

Однако charset="utf-8" вставлен, а проблема отображения русских надписей остается!
Что делать в таком случае?

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте сменить кодировку самого файла на utf-8. Это можно сделать например в notepad++

Comment: Прошу уточнить в каком файле? В котором размещен скрипт? Правильно понял?

Answer (score 0):

Да скорее всего у вас файлы в кодировке отличной от utf-8, Открываете файл notepad++ -> кодировки -> преобразовать в utf-8 , ctrl+s